# Tutorial on how to load up your own ERC20 EOS token using a template contract.

Tags: smart-contract, tokens, eosio.token

I have the following template contract: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts/eosio.token

Is there a step by step tutorial on what I need to do to load up my own token? What are the general steps to get to the final product of owning your own token? Do I need to modify any EOS contract code in those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same functionality as it is in eosio.token you need to follow this https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/token-contract as shown in this documentation by eosio you can have your own final product with the token. If you need different functionality than this contract then you need to change contract as per your need.